# Pass json data to JavaScript without creating new object

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I am querying json data from database then performing some filtering and further procedures. After that I want to display that data on map, so I am passing it through JSInterop to JavaScript. Everything seems to be working except that on each method execution I am getting new map on my webpage. So after executing method 4 times, I am having 4 maps on web page.

Please comment, if additional code is necessary...

Index.razor:

```
<div>
  <select id="layer-select" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <option value="osm" selected>Open Street Map</option>
  </select>

  <div class="card-body p-0">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
      <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
      <div id="popup-content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Index.razor.cs:

```
[Inject] IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
...

private async Task UpdateData()
{
  this.SelectedDate = this.SelectedDate.Value.AddDays(1);

  this.FilteredDataRecords = this.DataRecords
   .Where(w => w.TimeNow.Date == SelectedDate.Value.Date && (w.Latitude != 0 || w.Longitude != 0))
   .OrderBy(o => o.TimeNow)
   .ToList();

  string jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(this.FilteredDataRecords);

  await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("olMap.showMap", jsonData);
}
```

map.js:

```
window.olMap = {
  showMap: function (jsonData) {

    var HereLayers = [
      {
        base: 'base',
        type: 'maptile',
        scheme: 'osm',
      },
    ];

    ...

    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
     source: loadMarineData(JSON.parse(jsonData)), //JSON.parse(jsonData)
      visible: true,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: '#d12710', width: 4 })
      })
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
      overlays: [overlay],
      target: 'map',
      layers: layers,
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([25.2849, 60.0917]),
        zoom: 8
      })
    });

    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    map.addLayer(nauticLayer);

   ....

    var select = document.getElementById('layer-select');

    function onChange() {
      var scheme = select.value;
      for (var i = 0, ii = layers.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        layers[i].setVisible(HereLayers[i].scheme === scheme);
      }
    }

    select.addEventListener('change', onChange);

    onChange();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've not used this map engine before but i would suggest

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  overlays: [overlay],
  target: 'map',
  layers: layers,
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([25.2849, 60.0917]),
    zoom: 8
  })
});
```

should be

```
if(! document.map){
     document.map = new ol.Map({
      overlays: [overlay],
      target: 'map',
      layers: layers,
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([25.2849, 60.0917]),
        zoom: 8
      })
    });
}
const map = document.map
```

this basically says get the already created map and only create a new map it if doesn't exist

just remember that because you are using the same map over and over again you will need to clean up the previous runs yourself

ie before

```
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
map.addLayer(nauticLayer
```

do

```
for(const layer of map.getLayers())
{
    map.removeLayer(layer)
}
```

(note this is example code to demonstrate the idea, not functioning code)

you should also avoid the `var` keyword instead you should use `const` and `let` var is a hold over from the early days of JS before the introduction of scoping and it has some nasty side effects if you use it in the wrong way

Comment: Thank you! This almost works. However after adding `map.getLayers().getArray().forEach(layer => map.removeLayer(layer));` I don't see the map and after removing it my layers are added on top of each other without updating. I marked as an answer already however...

Comment: well as i said i've not used that map engine so not familiar with its quirks

Comment: @LG3 another option could be to move the addlayer call inside the if statement if they are fixed and don't need updating for every rerun of your code

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will try to figure it out, otherwise ask question in OpenLayers section

Comment: in case you want an alternative https://leafletjs.com is my mapping engine of choice, i find it works in almost all situations and has great documentation

Comment: So you say it is better than OL? I will check it out. Just starting with maps

Comment: Like i said not tried OL so i can't comment on if its better or not, but its the product i use and have no cause for complaints